# Creating a clock class in Java

Tags: java, swing, class, time

I would like to create my own Time class which can accept the hour minute and second in the constructor. Then I want to be able to use a getCurrentTime() method and return the updated time (if the time was 12:00:00 when the object was created and a minute and 15 seconds have passed then it should return 12:01:15).

I would like to be able to implement this using the 12 and 24 hour clock. I know System.currentTimeMillis() can be used to calculate elapsed time in milliseconds, and I know that the swing package has a timer that might be useful.

Can anybody give me any pointers on the most efficient/ practical way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like the people on stackoverflow should do your homework ...

Comment: As a beginner you should probably not care about "most efficient" *right now*: Implement it in a way that **you can do**. Then, ask if that's a good way or if there's something inherently wrong. That way you will learn *a lot more* and *a lot quicker*.

Comment: I'm not sure of what exactly it is that you want, but have a look at the `Date` and `Calendar` classes - and if you want to use an external library: JodaTime.

Comment: You need to be more explicit on your question. Is this a homework?

Comment: Is this a homework question?  If so, please do not ask Stack Overflow to do your homework.  Attempt the problem yourself and then post your code and we can help debug and fix it.

Comment: @ERIK Yeah it is a homework question, and I wasn't asking for the code to be typed up for me, just a suggestion that might point me in the right direction, more so than my teachers vague instructions. Feel free to not do my homework for me and move on, I'm just trying to learn what I can.

Comment: @cloud311 then you should accept the answer of AlexR an go the way Joachim Sauer pointed you out.

Comment: What are hour, minute and second in the constructor used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `java.util.Calendar`. It will give you all tools you need for quick start.